# jQuery - $.data() - data is lost when accessed from another function - returns undefined

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to store a javascript object in a list element, which appears to be working fine, until I try accessing that data from another function.

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RaUxB/2/

Here's my javascript:

```
var showData = function (li) {
    // get the stored data
    var d = $.data(li, 'testData');
    if (typeof(d) === 'undefined')
        alert ('showData() - data is undefined!');
    else
        alert ('showData() - number: [' + d.number+ '], text: [' + d.text + ']');
};

var doStuff = function () {
    $('#list').children().each(function(ix, item) {
        showData(item);
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    // create a list item
    var li = $('<li>List Item 1 - Click Me!</li>').appendTo('#list');

    // store some data in it
    $.data(li, 'testData', {number:1, text:'test 1'});

    // show the data - this works!!!
    showData(li);

    // assign a click handler that will also show the data
    $(li).click(function() {
        showData(this); // this doesn't work!!!
    });
});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
<p><a href="#" onclick="javascript:doStuff();return(false);">Try This Way</a></p>
```

​

Answer (score 2):

`$.data` takes a raw object, not a jQuery object representing a DOM element.

Calling `$.data($(...))` associates the data with that jQuery object wrapper, not the element.

You should use `$(...).data()`, which will work.
Alternatively, pass `elem[0]` to `$.data()` to operate on the raw DOM element everywhere.

Comment: According to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/, it takes an element, a key and a value

Comment: @Redtopia: Exactly.  A **DOM element**, not a jQuery object.

Comment: OK, that's where I was confused. When reading through jquery docs, I tend to think of references to elements as jquery objects. Not in this case... my mistake! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you are originally calling `.showData(li)`, **LI** is the one with the `.data()` stored onto it.

Try adding this to your `.click()` event:

You should be storing the data onto the -this- element.

```
$(li).click(function() {
    // store some data into THIS - now the correct .data will be stored
    $.data(this, 'testData', {number:1, text:'test 1'});
          // ^^

    showData(this); // this (now has data) and will work
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xtwru/1/)